# Sending PDF with Fast Web View in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, pdf

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 + IIS 7 to serve up a number of large PDFs via `Response.TransmitFile`.

The PDFs are all linearized, i.e. "Fast Web View". However the browser still requires the entire PDF to be downloaded before displaying any of it. All I want to do is show the first page (at least) without having to wait several minutes for the entire PDF to download.

From what I have read, the response header should include ["Accept-Ranges", "bytes"] but this does not seem to help.

Can anyone give me some pointers?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this.  Anything else besides storing it on the hd and letting http serve it?

Comment: Any updates on this? We are currently looking for solution for this as well...

Comment: We have tried using OWIN StaticFiles, it does not work as well...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that easily. For byte range to work you would need many requests to serve the same file. How would you associate all these requests with a single file instance? You would probaly need to save the file to disk or somehonw maintain the file in memory... it could get tricky...

Much simpler would be to save PDFs in a shared folder (a first in first out cache) and let the HTTP 1.1 do the rest.